# Как обратиться к предыдущей строке таблицы из ячейки?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

HTML:

```
<tr class="product" id="123">...<tr>
<tr class="advert">
    <td>
         <a class="enable">Enable</a>
    <td>
</tr>
```

Элементов с классом `advert` может быть несколько. При клике на ссылку нужно обратиться к вышестоящей ячейке с классом `product` и получить её ID.

Пытаюсь это сделать:

```
$('.enable').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var id = String($(this).parent().prevAll('.product:first').attr('id')).substr(3);
    console.log('id = ' + id);
});
```

В переменной `id` получаю `undefined`.

Как правильно получить ID?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.parent()` возвращает непосредственного родителя, которым в данном случае является `<td>`. Вместо этого можно использовать `.parents('.advert')` или `.closest('.advert')`:

```js
$('.enable').click(function() {
    var id = $(this).closest('.advert').prevAll('.product:first').attr('id');
    console.log('id = ' + id);
});
```

```html
<table>
    <tr class="product" id="123">...<tr>
    <tr class="advert">
        <td>
             <a class="enable">Enable</a>
        <td>
    </tr>
</table>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Благодарю. Разобрался.